# How to convert query string from url in shiny to an accent string

Tags: r

I'm working with a shiny app that gets a query string from the url using the `parseQueryString()` function.

When the user searchs for `"história"`, for example, the query string comes like this:

```
histÃ³ria
```

i've managed to convert it to a "no accent" string, with this function:

```
iconv(query_termo, from="UTF-8", to="ASCII//TRANSLIT")
print(query_termo)
"historia"
```

now i need to save the string with the accent so i can print it.

I've tried this:

```
 Encoding(query_termo) <- "latin1"
```

but it comes out like this:

```
histÃƒÂ³ria
```

i need to get the term like the original one typed: `"história"`.

any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

ó is equivalent to "&oacute";

Try to use it in your R code

```
library(htmltools)
library(shiny)
ui <- HTML('
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <p>hist&oacute;ria</p>

  </body>
  </html>')


server <- function(input, output){}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: i need a general solution, yours only apply to one specific word.